# Which is faster: access repository directly or use hashmap with the results from it?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, hashmap

I have a service with Hibernate. And I want to make it work as fast as possible.
Would it be better to store all my tables into hashmaps in the beginning, and then use it to access entities, or it would be the same as using `repo.findById()` method? I am working with data within one transaction.
I've heard that hibernate caches all the results until the end of the transaction and if so, then I assume `findById()` would work with the same speed. But I just want to make sure)

Comment: hibernate has a built-in 1st level cache, and you can set up a 2nd level cache with ehcache. a DIY option like using hashmap is going to be a lot of trouble and will be error-prone.

Comment: And depending on your database you will notice that you don't need a cache at all. Simply don't read entities if you don't want to change them. Read DTOs. If you need JSON you can read that from the DB as well

Comment: https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/#:~:text=%E2%80%9CPremature%20optimization%20is%20the%20root,famous%20saying%20among%20software%20developers.&text=%E2%80%9CThe%20real%20problem%20is%20that,of%20it)%20in%20programming.%E2%80%9D